# Is it possible to upload the build to the same app created in Appstore connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, platform

I have one app that is already live on AppStore and it is developed using ionic. Now we decided to re-develop the same app using another platform like native or flutter.
Is it possible to upload the build to the same app created in Appstore connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and quite common.

A new version of your application can replace the old one regardless of differences in code base, visual design or logic. Technically speaking you could upload a new version which is a completely different application from the previous one and users would see it as an update.

This specific example of yours happens a lot. Application is at one time developed with some cross platform tools and then later with native tools or vice versa. Or sometimes even the same platform is used but a complete rewrite is being made.

One of challenges you may face though is how to preserve local user data (if you have any). If your current application stores some user-generated data into some database then the new application needs to be able to hook into the same database. Alternative is to have an intermediate update using Ionic which prepares data for migration to the new version (drop everything into some JSON on local storage for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You can upload any number of builds to same app. All you need to do is

1. Open an app on AppStoreConnect.
2. Create a version (like 1.0) on
   AppStoreConnect, if not already created.
3. Update your target version
   in xCode to match just created app version.
4. Update your build
   number, as you can't upload same build number on same app version.
5. Archive using xCode.
6. Upload a build using xCode or Transporter.
7. Update required information.
8. Submit for review.
9. Cheer-up!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to upload new binary over the existing binary in App Store Connect. No matter which technology you have used during development. You just need to set the same bundle identifier which is used in existing Binary and upload through Xcode.